# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the userRepository (?)

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Estoy aprendiendo a usar NestJS, to me estaba marchando bien hasta que me apareció un error, y sinceramente no encontré respuestas contundentes que me dieran una solución, cuando trato de correr mediante `npm run start:dev` me aparece este error, estuve buscando soluciones pero no encuentro alguna.

```
   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the userRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.
    
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the userRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Connection is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
- If Connection is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
+
```

**user.module**

```
    @Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([user])
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService, ]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

**user.service**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(user)
        private readonly userRepository: Repository<user>
     ){}

     async getMany(){
         return await this.userRepository.find()
     }

     async getOne(id: number){
         const user = await this.userRepository.findOne(id);
         if(!user) throw new NotFoundException ('User doesnt exist')

         return user;
     }

     async createOne(dto: CreateUserDto){
         const newUser = this.userRepository.create(dto)
         return await this.userRepository.save(newUser)
     }
     
     async editOne(){}

     async deleteOne(){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nestjs no encuentra los objetos que deben ser inyectados en tus repositorios. Por eso te indica que debes revisar la conexión que tienes en TypeOrmModule.forRoot() en AppModule o el archivo ormconfig.json.

Allí debes indicar la entidad user o la ruta de donde esta la entidad para cargar los objectos.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ... otras opciones
      entities: [user],
    })
```

o en el archivo orconfig.json

```
{
  ..otras opciones
  "entities": ["dist/**/*{.ts,.js}"],
}
```